# [ffmpeg-devel]How to use ffmpeg filter to implementation left and right split screen

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I want to achieve left and right split screen,and i follow this code to implementation.but it not work.

I don't know it's a problem with the description string or a link problem,anyone know?

I read yuv data, write yuv data

ffmpeg version is 6.1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavfilter/avfilter.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersink.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
}
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib,"avcodec.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"avdevice.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"avfilter.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"avformat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"avutil.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"swresample.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"swscale.lib")

static void saveFrame(AVFrame* frame, FILE* out)
{
    int width = frame->width;
    int height = frame->height;
    // save Y
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        fwrite(frame->data[0] + i * frame->linesize[0], 1, frame->width, out);
    }
    // save U
    for (int i = 0; i < height / 2; i++)
    {
        fwrite(frame->data[1] + i * frame->linesize[1], 1, frame->width / 2, out);
    }
    // save V
    for (int i = 0; i < height / 2; i++)
    {
        fwrite(frame->data[2] + i * frame->linesize[2], 1, frame->width / 2, out);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int ret;
    FILE* fp1 = NULL;
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    AVFilterContext* buffer_ctx1;
    AVFilterContext* buffer_ctx2;
    AVFilterContext* buffersink_ctx;
    AVFilterGraph* filter_graph;
    AVFilterInOut* inputs = NULL;
    AVFilterInOut* outputs = NULL;
    char filter_args[1024] = { 0 };
    char err_buf[512];

    const char* infile1 = "D:\\windows-ffmpeg\\x64\\output_1.yuv";
    const char* outfile = "D:\\windows-ffmpeg\\x64\\output_w.yuv";
    fp1 = fopen(infile1, "rb");
    if (!fp1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "infile %s open failed\n", infile1);
        exit(0);
    }
    fp = fopen(outfile, "wb");
    if (!fp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "outfile %s open failed\n", outfile);
        exit(0);
    }
    filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();
    if (!filter_graph)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: avfilter_graph_alloc\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    if (avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffer_ctx1, avfilter_get_by_name("buffer"), "in0", "video_size=720x480:pix_fmt=0:time_base=1/24", NULL, filter_graph) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: avfilter_graph_create_filter\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffer_ctx2, avfilter_get_by_name("buffer"), "in1", "video_size=720x480:pix_fmt=0:time_base=1/24", NULL, filter_graph) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: avfilter_graph_create_filter\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink"), "out", NULL, NULL, filter_graph) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: avfilter_graph_create_filter\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    AVFilterInOut** ppSt_AVFilters = (AVFilterInOut**)av_malloc(2 * sizeof(AVFilterInOut*));

    ppSt_AVFilters[1] = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    ppSt_AVFilters[1]->name = av_strdup("in1");
    ppSt_AVFilters[1]->filter_ctx = buffer_ctx2;
    ppSt_AVFilters[1]->pad_idx = 0;
    ppSt_AVFilters[1]->next = NULL;

    ppSt_AVFilters[0] = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    ppSt_AVFilters[0]->name = av_strdup("in0");
    ppSt_AVFilters[0]->filter_ctx = buffer_ctx1;
    ppSt_AVFilters[0]->pad_idx = 0;
    ppSt_AVFilters[0]->next = ppSt_AVFilters[1];

    AVFilterInOut* pSt_AVFilterIn = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    pSt_AVFilterIn->name = av_strdup("out");
    pSt_AVFilterIn->filter_ctx = buffersink_ctx;
    pSt_AVFilterIn->pad_idx = 0;
    pSt_AVFilterIn->next = NULL;

    //sprintf(filter_args, "[in0]split[main][tmp];[tmp]scale=w=380:h=480[inn0];[main][inn0]overlay=0:0[x1];[in1]scale=w=380:h=480[inn1];[x1][inn1]overlay=380:0[out]");
    sprintf(filter_args,
        "pad=size=720x480 [base];"
        "[in0] scale=380x480 [left];"
        "[in1] scale=380x480 [right];"
        "[base][left] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];"
        "[tmp1][right] overlay=shortest=1:x=380");
        
    ret = avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(filter_graph, filter_args, &pSt_AVFilterIn, ppSt_AVFilters, NULL);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        av_strerror(ret, err_buf, sizeof(err_buf));
        fprintf(stderr, "error:avfilter_graph_parse2 %s\n", err_buf);
        exit(0);
    }

    ret = avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, NULL);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        av_strerror(ret, err_buf, sizeof(err_buf));
        fprintf(stderr, "error:avfilter_graph_config %s\n", err_buf);
        exit(0);
    }

    int nSize = 720 * 480 * 3 / 2;
    uint8_t* ptszWBBuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(nSize);
    uint8_t* ptszRBBuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(nSize);

    while (1)
    {
        AVFrame* src_frame1 = av_frame_alloc();
        AVFrame* src_frame2 = av_frame_alloc();

        src_frame1->width = 720;
        src_frame1->height = 480;
        src_frame1->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

        src_frame2->width = 720;
        src_frame2->height = 480;
        src_frame2->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
        av_frame_get_buffer(src_frame1, 32);
        av_frame_get_buffer(src_frame2, 32);

        int nRet = fread(ptszRBBuffer, 1, nSize, fp1);
        if (nRet <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "add buffersrc1\n");

        int nSize = 720 * 480;
        src_frame1->data[0] = ptszRBBuffer;
        src_frame1->data[1] = ptszRBBuffer + nSize;
        src_frame1->data[2] = ptszRBBuffer + nSize * 5 / 4;

        ret = av_buffersrc_add_frame(buffer_ctx1, src_frame1);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            av_strerror(ret, err_buf, sizeof(err_buf));
            fprintf(stderr, "buffersrc1 add frame error %s\n", err_buf);
            break;
        }

        fprintf(stdout, "add buffersrc2\n");
        src_frame2->data[0] = ptszRBBuffer;
        src_frame2->data[1] = ptszRBBuffer + nSize;
        src_frame2->data[2] = ptszRBBuffer + nSize * 5 / 4;
        ret = av_buffersrc_add_frame(buffer_ctx2, src_frame2);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            av_strerror(ret, err_buf, sizeof(err_buf));
            fprintf(stderr, "buffersrc2 add frame error %s\n", err_buf);
            break;
        }
        AVFrame* out_frame = av_frame_alloc();
        fprintf(stdout, "get buffersink\n");
        ret = av_buffersink_get_frame(buffersink_ctx, out_frame);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            av_strerror(ret, err_buf, sizeof(err_buf));
            fprintf(stderr, "buffersink get frame error %s\n", err_buf);
            av_frame_free(&out_frame);
            break;
        }
        saveFrame(out_frame, fp);
        av_frame_unref(out_frame);
        av_frame_free(&src_frame1);
        av_frame_free(&src_frame2);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "success\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I want to implementation left and right split screen or multi-grid screen

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.